# Windows Server 2012 R2 cannot rename Administrator account via GPO

Tags: group-policy, windows-server-2012-r2

On Windows Server 2012 R2 the Administrator account does not seem to be able to be renamed.

Have created the normal Rename Administrator GPO:
Comp config -> Policies -> Windows settings -> Security settings -> local policies -> Security options
Accounts: Rename Administrator Account

But GPO does not get applied for some reason, RSOP indicated the policy engine did not attempt to configure the setting.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Has the administrator account already been renamed manually, or by another policy?

Comment: Not that I can see